# Why humans commit sins when you are around us Uddhava to Lord Krishna

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

Uddhava was friend of Lord Krishna right from childhood. While departing from earth , Lord Krishna said to Uddhava  that -many  persons has benefitted from me during my  this avatara , by asking I need wealth; I need health  etc. But you have not asked anything. What is in your mind ask me

Then Uddhava asked-:

1. Krishna You are saying all the time I am with all the human beings. But why we commit sins if you are around us? What was Krishna's reply for this?

Comment: Your second question is also not present in Uddhav Gita part of SB Canto 11.

Comment: @swift---I need the answer for that. You cannot find in Uddhav Gita. That is why I need the word duplicate to be removed.

Comment: OK , then i think you need to reword your question a little bit so that both will be different.Like - is this question was  asked by Uddhava to shree Krishna ? and what was Shree krishna's  reply etc.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Answer is Krishna told Uddhava that all the time I will be around all the humans  as sakshi bootham. I will not interfere in Karma of a human. It will function accordingly .Whatever you do I know.When humans forget  me [sakshi boootham] they will commit sins. Hence I protect all with blessings. Recd this from a watsapp message--source not known.

Answer (score 2):

**Krishna and Uddhava did not talk about this.**  The only conversation at length between Krishna and Uddhava is the Uddhava Gita, which occurs in the [11th Skandha](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11) of the Srimad Bhagavatam.  And it contains no discussion along the lines you're describing.